# Why method renaming does not work in PHP traits?

Tags: php, traits

I use PHP 7.1.0.

Let's say we have a trait, we use it inside a class and rename the imported method:

```
trait T
{
    public function A() {
        echo ".";
    }
}

class C
{
    use T {
        A as B;
    }
}

$c = new C();
$c->B();
$c->A(); // Why does it work?
```

Why does PHP still allow me to use old method name (`A` in this case)?

It's really a pain because in more complex examples you cannot rely on method renaming - and thus you can unexpectedly receive "incompatible declarations" error:

```
class BaseSrc
{
}

trait BaseTrait
{
    public function init(BaseSrc $baseSrc)
    {
        echo "Init Base";
    }
}

class Base
{
    use BaseTrait {
        BaseTrait::init as initBase;
    }
}

$base = new Base();
$base->initBase(new BaseSrc());
$base->init(new BaseSrc()); // WHY DOES IT WORK?????

class MainSrc extends BaseSrc
{
}

trait MainTrait
{
    use BaseTrait {
        BaseTrait::init as initBase;
    }

    public function init(MainSrc $mainSrc)
    {
        $this->initBase($mainSrc);
        echo "Init Main";
    }
}

// Warning: Declaration of MainTrait::init(MainSrc $mainSrc) should be compatible with Base::init(BaseSrc $baseSrc)
class Main extends Base
{
    use MainTrait;
}
```

I think, this code should work. Since I renamed `init()` into `initBase()` in the `Base` class AND did the same renaming when using `BaseTrait` inside `MainTrait`, I expect that this method (`BaseTrait::init()`) will not conflict with `MainTrait::init()`. In fact, PHP says that I have incompatible declarations. The reason behind it is that renaming `init as initBase` does not work - method `init` is still there, in my `Base` class!

Is there any way how to solve this problem without renaming BaseTrait::init() into something like BaseTrait::initBase() from the very beginning (not just in the `use` statement)?

Should I consider this as a PHP bug and report it? Is there anything reasonable behind this behaviour?

Comment: what php.net writes about: `The Aliased_Talker makes use of the as operator to be able to use B's bigTalk implementation under an` **additional** `alias talk.` - http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php. So `as` adds alias but does not replace method. And then: `the as operator can be used to add an alias to one of the methods. Note the as operator does not rename the method and it does not affect any other method either.`'

Comment: @splash58 OK, thanks. I see: "as" is not renaming, it's just "aliasing" (honestly, I did not mention this note while reading this page about traits). Is there a reason behind it? I mean, any advantages of aliasing instead of renaming? From my point of view, it's very inconvenient.

Comment: I think `insteadof`  make what you want. Am I wrong? I don't know trait so deep

Comment: @splash58 insteadof works only if you use 2 traits in the same class (as far as I know). I experimented with it and could not apply it to my situation.

Comment: Obviously aliasing required when method in your class has __the same name__ as method in trait. And as trait methods are __overwritten__ by methods of class, which you don't want usually, you use aliasing. Add method `A` to your class and test.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments and for completeness; From the [PHP manual section on Traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php):

> The `Aliased_Talker` makes use of the as operator to be able to use
>   B's `bigTalk` implementation under an additional alias talk.

And then:

> The as operator can be used to add an alias to one of the methods.
>   Note the as operator does not rename the method and it does not affect
>   any other method either.

So `as` adds an alias but does not replace or affect the original method in any way. This is the expected behavior.