# How to use a PHP trait in another trait without conflict?

Tags: php, oop, metaprogramming, traits

So basically this is the code : In my trait Greeting I want to use another very helpful trait Word. But now if a class uses Greeting, it can not use Word anymore, although I used an alias.

Of course I can use `insteadof` but it is not obvious for someone using my library where the error comes from and which traits are involved. Why is there a conflict here and is there a syntax trick to avoid the use of instead of ? Thank you.

```
trait Word {
    public function hello()
    {
        return 'hello';
    }
}

trait Greeting {
    use Word {
        Word::hello as _word_hello;
    }
    public function greet($name)
    {
        return $this->_word_hello() . " $name";
    }
}

class Test {
    use Word;
    use Greeting;
}

PHP Fatal error:  Trait method hello has not been applied, because there are collisions with other trait methods on Test in traits.php on line 20
```

Comment: why do you use the Word trait two times? as long as Greeting uses Word trait, you can use that trait -Word- within your Test class!

Comment: @hassan OP is asking whether it's possible to make that an internal implementation detail that exhibiting classes of `Greeting` don't need to know about.

Comment: @deceze exactly

Comment: @deceze in my IMHO, a wrong implementation will lead to a wrong result, why do you need to duplicate a trait call in the same class?

Comment: @hassan, it is not duplicating on purpose. It is just a case when a class needs two different traits, but for some reason one of the traits uses the second as an implementation detail, to implements in-trait methods.

Like if you need a TranslationTrait and a StringHelperTrait in a web controller, and the developer of TranslationTrait uses the StringHelperTrait because its convenient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after a small research I found that the `as` operator for traits functions creates an alias but does not rename the function. So the `Greeting` trait still creates a `hello` function in the class that uses it.

Related question : [Why method renaming does not work in PHP traits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43836171/why-method-renaming-does-not-work-in-php-traits)

(As a personal note I think this is very bad design).

Answer (score 0):

Possible Solution to (Parent)Trait using another Trait, while a class uses both:

ParentTrait:

```
use App\MyTrait as _MyTrait;

trait ParentTrait
{
    use _MyTrait {
        _MyTrait::someFunction as _someFunction;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`Word` is already exists in `Greeting` so there is no need to define it again in `Test`, and for this reason you get that error:

```
trait Word {
    public function hello()
    {
        return 'hello';
    }
}

trait Greeting {
    use Word {
        Word::hello as _word_hello;
    }
    public function greet($name)
    {
        return $this->_word_hello() . " $name";
    }
}

class Test {
    #use Word;
    use Greeting;
}
$test = new Test();
echo $test->greet("Ahmad");
```